# Want to set cursor position in Spark textinput control in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I use Flex 4.5. I want to set cursor position based on integer variable. For example if my variable value is 5 then cursor in textbox will point to position 5. So there is any way to achieve this??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 textInput.setFocus();
 textInput.selectRange(caretPosition, caretPosition);
```

Comment: actually I use Spark inputtext control and when I am changes any text then cursor focus automatically goes in last index. So how I can prevent it??

Comment: If you want to handle only programmaticaly text change then handle FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT or
if you want to handle only user editing operation then handle TextOperationEvent.CHANGE.
Update cursor position on this events.